# I want to create Web api in .net without mvc to store and retrive data in sql

Tags: javascript, .net, sql-server

I want to create Web api in .NET without MVC to store and retrive data in SQL and want to use that API in another web application using JavaScript. In the data filed there should be Id, comment, date and name.

I have tried the following code in Repository class but its not working .

```
public string markupdata(jsondetails jsoninfo)
{

    string Message;
    SqlConnection con = null;
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Markup_table(Json_Data,comment_date,model_name) values(@Json_Data,@comment_date,@model_name)", con);
    //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Json_Data", jsoninfo.Json_Data);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment_date", jsoninfo.comment_date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model_name", jsoninfo.model_name);
    con.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        Message = jsoninfo.Json_Data + " Details inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        Message = jsoninfo.Json_Data + " Details not inserted successfully";
    }
    con.Close();
    return Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a string as JSON content to the client by using  `JavaScriptSerializer class (add the reference to System.Web.Extensions)` and 
replacing:

```
return Message;
```

to

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Message);
```

and in `javaScript` you can serve and parse the response like:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(response);
```